# VBA Data Scraping from Websites

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

document.getElementsByTagName("tr").length returns zero when I execute a VBA script to find the number of tr elements on a specific web page

```
Sub AutomaticMode()
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://www.example.com/"
Do While IE.readyState < 4
    Application.StatusBar = "DOM Loading ..."
Loop
Set username_field = IE.document.getElementByID("username")
username_field.Value = "username"
Set password_field = IE.document.getElementByID("password")
password_field.Value = "password"
SendKeys "{Tab}{Enter}"
Do While IE.readyState < 4
    Application.StatusBar = "DOM Loading ..."
Loop
Dim trList As IHTMLElementCollection
Set trList = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
MsgBox (trList.Length)
End Sub
```

Comment: What about `trList.Count`?

Comment: trList.Count makes the program return an error: "Object doesn't support this property or method"

trList is an IHTMLElementCollection if that is of any help

Comment: If you put a break on the `Set trList = ...` line and wait a little while before continuing execution, does that change the outcome ?

Comment: Try declaring `trList` like this instead: `Dim trList As Object`, then try using `.count`

Comment: i just tested that for 'div' it is returning the correct length - 18 divs total - but for tr it is not and the page is not showing any frames in its source code as well (considering that the tr's may be in a separate frame)

Comment: and Dim trList As Object returns an error "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tr tags found on your website can be caused by macro being executed before page fully loads. Try changing:

```
Do While IE.readyState < 4
```

to:

```
Do While IE.readyState < 4 or IE.Busy
```

Even this doesn't guarantee that everything loads before firing macro, but often helps and is a good practice to always include it. Sometimes you need to find object which displays "loading" etc. in frontend and loop through HTML elements until it disappears - then you are safe to run your script.

Comment: Good point, but I would go for `Or` instead of `And` just to be extra safe. Still doesn't guarantee anything though.

Comment: Thanks!

Your answer is correct. Although `Do While IE.readyState < 4 and IE.Busy` didn't return the results, but the problem was that the 'tr' elements were loading sometime after the page loaded. 

On putting the script on `Wait` for 5 seconds before it started looking for tr's, it finally returned them!

Thanks again!!

Comment: It is true that the statement should be with "or", not "and", my mistake as I got used to condition with "until".